# MongoDB Transactions In NodeJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections.
I'd like to update the following documents while making sure that both pass or if one fails then abort.
I saw some videos like the following [MongoDB transactions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnciVR4Bysw) but still need a real example.

in the video `time 34:46` they show very simple example but where `session` is coming from?

```
stockItemAdd(req, res) {

  collection_1 = await Inventory.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: '1' },
    { $set: {
      name: 'red_box',
      catalogNumber: 'AAA',
      quantity: req.body.quantity
    }}
  ).exec()


  collection_2  = await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(
    { catalogNumber: 'AAA' },
    { $inc: {
      quantity: req.body.quantity,
    }}
  ).exec()

}
```

Comment: [Transaction syntax in video](https://youtu.be/tnciVR4Bysw?t=2057)?  You may want to review [_"Transactions in Mongoose"_](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) too.

Comment: In the video, `session` is part of the function parameters, you create one using the `MongoClient` object, like `client.startSession()`