# MongoDB transactions, the callback API approach

Tags: database, mongodb, go, transactions, mongo-go

Having read many doc/articles on MongoDB transactions, I still need further clarification.

[Here](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/mongodb-transactions) it says:

> MongoDB provides two APIs to use transactions. The first is the core API which has similar syntax to relational databases. The second, the callback API, is the *recommended* approach to using transactions in MongoDB.

Yet it went on introduced the core API approach, and did not touch the recommended approach at all.

The official doc [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/) says,

> This example highlights the key components of the transactions API. In particular, it uses the callback API. The callback API:
>
> - starts a transaction
> - executes the specified operations
> - commits the result (or aborts on error)

However, when it comes to the most important *"executes the specified operations"* step, the example didn't shown any relevant code. I.e., as asked in [MongoDB Transactions In NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201259/mongodb-transactions-in-nodejs), I *"still need a real example"*.

PS. In case the example get changed or goes away, here is the Golang version:

```golang
// WithTransactionExample is an example of using the Session.WithTransaction function.
func WithTransactionExample(ctx context.Context) error {
    // For a replica set, include the replica set name and a seedlist of the members in the URI string; e.g.
    // uri := "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl"
    // For a sharded cluster, connect to the mongos instances; e.g.
    // uri := "mongodb://mongos0.example.com:27017,mongos1.example.com:27017/"
    uri := mtest.ClusterURI()
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() { _ = client.Disconnect(ctx) }()
    // Prereq: Create collections.
    wcMajority := writeconcern.Majority()
    wcMajority.WTimeout = 1 * time.Second
    wcMajorityCollectionOpts := options.Collection().SetWriteConcern(wcMajority)
    fooColl := client.Database("mydb1").Collection("foo", wcMajorityCollectionOpts)
    barColl := client.Database("mydb1").Collection("bar", wcMajorityCollectionOpts)
    // Step 1: Define the callback that specifies the sequence of operations to perform inside the transaction.
    callback := func(sessCtx mongo.SessionContext) (interface{}, error) {
        // Important: You must pass sessCtx as the Context parameter to the operations for them to be executed in the
        // transaction.
        if _, err := fooColl.InsertOne(sessCtx, bson.D{{"abc", 1}}); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if _, err := barColl.InsertOne(sessCtx, bson.D{{"xyz", 999}}); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return nil, nil
    }
    // Step 2: Start a session and run the callback using WithTransaction.
    session, err := client.StartSession()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer session.EndSession(ctx)
    result, err := session.WithTransaction(ctx, callback)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("result: %v\n", result)
    return nil
}
```

It looks to me from the example that the most important *"executes the specified operations"* step is done in callback. Is that so? If so, the official doc really needs to emphasize on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is complete. It contains this key comment:

```
// Step 2: Start a session and run the callback using WithTransaction.
```

So the `callback` function is executed by the [`Session.WithTransaction()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Session.WithTransaction)
method. You pass the `callback` function to it, and it will be called by the `Session.WithTransaction()` method.

The implementation ensures the operations done in the callback function will be executed as a transaction (that is, either all will be applied or none of them). If the callback function returns a non-`nil` error, the transaction will be aborted, else the transaction will be committed.