# Mongo-go driver version of session.copy()

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, mongo-go

I am migrating a go backend from using `mgo` to `mongo-go`. The service has lots of code and I have completed most of it except for a part that deals with `session.Copy()` method from the old `mgo`. The relevant snippet is below:

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)
...
type Store struct {
    session *mgo.Session
}


func (s *Store) collection(collectionName string) (*mgo.Session, *mgo.Collection) {
    session := s.session.Copy()
    collection := session.DB("").C(collectionName)

    return session, collection
}
```

I want to rewrite this while respecting the overall design but I am not certain what to do about that line `session := s.session.Copy()` - I want to do something like:

```
import(
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
)
type Store struct {
    client *mongo.Client
}


func (s *Store) collection(collectionName string) (*mongo.Client, *mongo.Collection) {
    client, err := s.client."what method to call here"
    if err != nil {
       //error will be handled here
    }
    collection := session.Database(DBName).Collection(collectionName)

    return session, collection
}
```

My understanding is that the `session.Copy()` method respects the original connection already in place but only starts a new session based on this as explained in here https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Copy .
There are several methods that seem like I can use and `m.client.StartSession(opts ...*options.SessionOptions)` looks like the natural candidate. But it's documentation is confusing me since the connection is already established in the `main.go` via something like:

```
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("URI")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mgo's session and mongo-go's session are 2 different entities.

[mgo's session](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session):

> Session represents a communication session with the database.

[mongo-go's session](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Session):

> Session is an interface that represents a MongoDB logical session. Sessions can be used to enable causal consistency for a group of operations or to execute operations in an ACID transaction.

mgo's session is a communication session and uses a single underlying connection. mongo-go's session is a logical session, and is not a replacement for mgo's session.

Primary use of mgo's session is to take advantage of multiple underlying connections. mongo-go manages an internal pool and you do not need to create a new session to use multiple connections. This is handled automatically and internally in mongo-go. You do not need to add anything to "replace" mgo's `session.Copy()`, omit that line.

See related questions:

[Concurrency in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (Mongo, Go)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492020/concurrency-in-gopkg-in-mgo-v2-mongo-go/42495522#42495522)

[MongoDB transactions, the callback API approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341159/mongodb-transactions-the-callback-api-approach/77341420#77341420)

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. The original method is called in several places like `session, collection : =s.collection("whatever collection name")` and then gets closed with `defer session.close()`. So if I am understanding correctly, I don't need to worry about deferring or closing at all using `mongo-go` like this in this function's example ?

Comment: @dezdichado Yes, that's right. With `mgo` you (have to) close the communication session. Since you have no such thing with mongo-go, you do not have to close anything. If anything, you only have to close the client on app close (`Client.Disconnect()`).